# Codeigniter shopping cart, view the contents in the cart page

Tags: php, codeigniter

Adding products to my cart is working fine, but after adding product to cart its not able to view it in my view page without refreshing view page,

I tried redirect() method still no use.
How do i view my page after adding products to cart.

Any help??

**my controller:**

```
<?php

class Cart extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addtocart($cal_id, $f_id) {
        if (empty($cal_id)) {
            $this->load->view('Cart_view');
        }
        $this->load->model('cart_model');
        $product = $this->cart_model->cart_contents($cal_id, $f_id);
        foreach ($product as $row) {
            $name = $row->title;
            $fees = $row->fees;
        }
        $product = array(
            'id' => $cal_id,
            'qty' => 1,
            'price' => $fees,
            'name' => $name,
        );
        print_r($product);
        $this->cart->insert($product);
        $this->load->view('Cart_view');
    }

    public function destroy() {
        $this->cart->destroy();
    }

}
?>
```

**my model:**

```
<?php

class cart_model extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function cart_contents($cal_id,$f_id)
    {
      $product=$this->db->select('*')
              ->from('calander')
              ->join('fees','calander.cal_id=fees.cal_id')
              ->where('fees.cal_id',$cal_id)
              ->where('fees.f_id',$f_id)
              ->get();
      return $product->result();

    }
}
?>
```

**my view**

```
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if ($cart = $this->cart->contents()) {
            ?><table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><u>Cart page</u></h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>course</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($cart as $contents) {
                    ?><tr>
                        <td><?php echo $contents['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $contents['qty']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $contents['price']; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php } ?>
            </table> <?php
           // redirect(base_url('/index.php/Cart/Cart_view'));
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for quick response,this is my first time in stack, so can you plz guide me to add code in my que?

Comment: Click ----->[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21846032/edit). Write your code.

Comment: here is my code.... thank u so much for very quick response....can you help in solving my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand what you are trying to do. When you load your view `$this->load->view('Cart_view');`, it is required to pass the data array, containing all the variables into the view like this `$this->load->view('Cart_view',$data);` . Without data array, view cannot display data. When ever you write code atleast, make variables names in such a way that other people will be able to understand what that variable stands for. Without enough data, i am taking the liberty of modifying your code

**Controller**

```
public function addtocart($cal_id, $f_id) {
        $data=array(
            'view'=>''
        );
        if (empty($cal_id)) {
            $this->load->view('Cart_view',$data);
        } else {
            $this->load->model('cart_model');
            $product = $this->cart_model->cart_contents($cal_id, $f_id);
            $data['view']='';
            foreach($product as $row):
                $data['view'].=' <tr>
                <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->qty.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->price.'</td>
                </tr>';
            endforeach; 
            $this->load->view('Cart_view',$data);
        }   
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
 public function cart_contents($cal_id,$f_id){
              $this->db->select('*')
              $this->db->from('calander')
              $this->db->join('fees','calander.cal_id=fees.cal_id')
              $this->db->where('fees.cal_id',$cal_id)
              $this->db->where('fees.f_id',$f_id);
              $query = $this->db->get();
              return $query->result();
    }
```

**view**

```
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><u>Cart page</u></h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>course</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <?php if($count>0){
                    echo $view;
                }?>
            </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for reply Akhil, In my code i am adding products to cart by $this->cart->insert() method; and retrieving it in view by $this->cart->contents(), inserting and display is fine. but after adding to the cart i have to refresh page to show cart content product.

Comment: Have you passed the data while loading the view ?? $this->load->view('Cart_view',$data); I havent seen the insert model function here

Comment: i think i dont need to pass any data from controller to view. because i can retrieve cart contents from $this->cart->contents(), so i am retrieving in my view and displaying it.

Comment: Usually in MVC, we try to maintain less PHP code in View.. hence its better to do it in controller then pass it to view. One more thing is, for listing & adding make it as a separate controller function so you can try reducing your line of code & make it less complicated.

Comment: Wow.. thank u so much its working fine.. i thought both will be same. but there is lot of difference i came to know.i am new to codeignter. thanku..

Comment: Well, actually try improving your code a bit. for listing make it one controller function & for input make it a seperate function. so after input if you want to list, you only need to call the list function. it will help you a lot in future if edits come.